# C# Quartz Complex Scheduling

Tags: c#, triggers, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I Want to create a trigger for my job that is not a SimpleSchedule, that will repeat forever or repeat x times. 
Which is the beat and right way to do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can reschedule the next occurrence as part of the task: you first schedule for instance on May 8. The task itself then calculates the next time to schedule the event and schedules it.

Comment: Thanks, but not possible in my case. The job is a generic job that gets its details from a db, and it can be repeated once a month, once a week, on several days, etc.

Comment: Use a cron expression? (see http://www.cronmaker.com/ to generate them).